# 'string' does not contain a definition for 'AsInt' in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to introduce below code in .Net core MVC 3.1 cshtml file:

```
<p id="DisableInfo">
    Your session will expire in @(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionExpNotice"].AsInt() / 6) minutes, Click Ok to remain logged in or click Cancel to log off.
    If you are logged off any changes will be lost.
</p>
```

But when in converted to .NET Core, I'm getting this error

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'AsInt' and no accessible extension method 'AsInt' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `.AsInt()` is an extension method in System.Web.WebPages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET Core,try to use :

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
<p id="DisableInfo">
        Your session will expire in @(Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["SessionExpNotice"]) / 6) minutes, Click Ok to remain logged in or click Cancel to log off.
        If you are logged off any changes will be lost.
    </p>
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  ...
  "SessionExpNotice": 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.AsInt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.stringextensions.asint?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) is an extension method for Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.

Alternative, convert to `int` type via `Convert.ToInt32()`.

```
@(Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionExpNotice"]) / 6)
```

Or else you need to implement the extension method for `string.AsInt()`.

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int AsInt(this string @value)
    {   
        return Int32.TryParse(@value, out int output) 
            ? output 
            : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `= 0` part of your method does not affect anything since the `out` parameter is guaranteed to be overwritten. Also, you do not use `isInt`, so it could be removed. But you are absolutely correct this gives the same behavior. The source of the original `AsInt` is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/main/src/System.Web.WebPages/StringExtensions.cs).